# Put OrderId from Flow to Apex

Tags: apex

I am Salesforce admin. I don't have skill of writing apex. Please, help me I need to get Order Id from Flow and use it in Apex. I already have Invokable method, but I can not add there an OrderId. Here is my code:

```
// Start Apex Class
public with sharing class CreateXeroInvoiceRunAsync {
    public CreateXeroInvoiceRunAsync() {
    }
    @InvocableMethod(label='Create Xero Invoice' description='Create Xero Invoice')
    public static void createXeroInvoice(List<Requests> requestList){
        List<Response> resToBeReturnedList = new List<Response>();
        List<Object> xeroInvoiceList = new List<Object>();
        String xeroOrgIdValue = '';

        for(Requests req : requestList){
            If(req.xeroOrgId != NULL && String.isNotBlank(req.xeroOrgId))
                xeroOrgIdValue = req.xeroOrgId;
            xeroInvoiceList.add(generateXeroInvoiceMap(req));
        }

        // Sending request to Xero via exposed Global API
        Map<String, Object> reqJSONMap = new Map<String, Object>(); 
        reqJSONMap.put('invoices' , xeroInvoiceList);
        String reqJSON = JSON.serialize(reqJSONMap); 

        Map<String, Object> finalReqMap = new Map<String, Object>(); 
        finalReqMap.put('version' , '1.0'); 
        finalReqMap.put('action' , 'createInvoice');
        finalReqMap.put('RequestJSON' , reqJSON); 
        If(xeroOrgIdValue != NULL && String.isNotBlank(xeroOrgIdValue))
            finalReqMap.put('xeroOrgId' , xeroOrgIdValue);
        System.debug('Request ::: ' + finalReqMap); 

        // Make a request to Xero
        Map<String, Object> respMap = Bread_Winner.BreadwinnerXeroAPI.call(finalReqMap);
        String respJSONString = String.valueof(respMap.get('responseJSON'));
        InvoiceListWrapper invWrapper = (InvoiceListWrapper)JSON.deserialize(respJSONString,InvoiceListWrapper.class);
        String invoiceId = invWrapper.invoices[0].SalesforceRecordId;
        Bread_Winner__Invoice__c singleInvoice = [SELECT Id, Order_Lookup__c  FROM Bread_Winner__Invoice__c where Id = :invoiceId limit 1];
        **singleInvoice.Order_Lookup__c  = '';**
            update singleInvoice;
        }
    public class InvoiceWrapper{
        public String SalesforceRecordId;
    }
    public class InvoiceListWrapper{
        public List<InvoiceWrapper> invoices;
    }


    public class Response{
        @InvocableVariable(label='status Code' description='Status of the request')
        public String statusCode;

        @InvocableVariable(label='Error' description='Error')
        public String error;
    }

    public class Requests{
        @InvocableVariable(label='Xero Org Id' description='Xero Org Id')
        public String xeroOrgId;

        @InvocableVariable(label='Xero Contact ID' description='Xero Contact ID')
        public String ContactID;

        @InvocableVariable(label='Date' description='Date')
        public Date DateString;

        @InvocableVariable(label='Due Date' description='Due Date')
        public Date DueDateString;

        @InvocableVariable(label='Status' description='Status')
        public String Status;

        @InvocableVariable(label='InvoiceNumber' description='InvoiceNumber')
        public String InvoiceNumber;
        
        @InvocableVariable(label='Reference' description='Reference')
        public String Reference;
        
        @InvocableVariable(label='OrderId' description='OrderId')
        public String OrderId;

        @InvocableVariable(label='Line Amount Types' description='Line Amount Types')
        public String LineAmountTypes;

        @InvocableVariable(label='Salesforce Account Id' description='Salesforce Account Id')
        public String Salesforce_Account_Id;

        @InvocableVariable(label='Salesforce Opportunity Id' description='Salesforce Opportunity Id')
        public String Salesforce_Opportunity_Id;

        @InvocableVariable(label='Line Item Code' description='Line Item Code')
        public STRING ItemCode;

        @InvocableVariable(label='Line Description' description='Line Description')
        public STRING Description;

        @InvocableVariable(label='Line Tax Type' description='Line Tax Type')
        public STRING TaxType;

        @InvocableVariable(label='Line Account Code' description='Line Account Code')
        public STRING AccountCode;

        @InvocableVariable(label='Line Line Item ID' description='Line Line Item ID')
        public STRING LineItemID;

        @InvocableVariable(label='Line Unit Amount' description='Line Unit Amount')
        public STRING UnitAmount;

        @InvocableVariable(label='Line Tax Amount' description='Line Tax Amount')
        public STRING TaxAmount;

        @InvocableVariable(label='Line Line Amount' description='Line Line Amount')
        public STRING LineAmount;

        @InvocableVariable(label='Line Quantity' description='Line Quantity')
        public STRING Quantity;

        @InvocableVariable(label='Line Discount Rate' description='Line Discount Rate')
        public STRING DiscountRate;

        @InvocableVariable(label='Line Tracking Category ID 1' description='Line Tracking Category ID 1')
        public STRING TrackingCategoryID1;

        @InvocableVariable(label='Line Tracking Category Name 1' description='Line Tracking Category Name 1')
        public STRING TrackingCategoryName1;

        @InvocableVariable(label='Line Tracking Category Option 1' description='Line Tracking Category Option 1')
        public STRING TrackingCategoryOption1;

        @InvocableVariable(label='Line Tracking Category ID 2' description='Line Tracking Category ID 2')
        public STRING TrackingCategoryID2;

        @InvocableVariable(label='Line Tracking Category Name 2' description='Line Tracking Category Name 2')
        public STRING TrackingCategoryName2;

        @InvocableVariable(label='Line Tracking Category Option 2' description='Line Tracking Category Option 2')
        public STRING TrackingCategoryOption2;

        @InvocableVariable(label='Invoice Line Items' description='Invoice Line Items') 
        public List<SObject> invoiceLines; 


    }

    public static Map<String, Object> generateXeroInvoiceMap(Requests req){
        Map<String, Object> xeroInvoiceMap = new Map<String, Object>(); 
        // Assign values from the Request to Xero Invoice
        Map<String,Object> xeroInvoiceContactRefMap = new Map<String,Object>();
        xeroInvoiceMap.put('Type','ACCREC');


        If(req.ContactID != NULL && String.isNotBlank(req.ContactID))
            xeroInvoiceContactRefMap.put('ContactID', req.ContactID);

        If(req.DateString != NULL)
            xeroInvoiceMap.put('DateString', DateTime.newInstance(req.DateString.year(), req.DateString.month(), req.DateString.day()).format('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss'));

        If(req.DueDateString != NULL)
            xeroInvoiceMap.put('DueDateString', DateTime.newInstance(req.DueDateString.year(), req.DueDateString.month(), req.DueDateString.day()).format('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss'));

        If(req.Status != NULL && String.isNotBlank(req.Status))
            xeroInvoiceMap.put('Status', req.Status);

        If(req.Reference != NULL && String.isNotBlank(req.Reference))
            xeroInvoiceMap.put('Reference', req.Reference);

        If(req.InvoiceNumber != NULL && String.isNotBlank(req.InvoiceNumber))
            xeroInvoiceMap.put('InvoiceNumber', req.InvoiceNumber);

        If(req.LineAmountTypes != NULL && String.isNotBlank(req.LineAmountTypes))
            xeroInvoiceMap.put('LineAmountTypes', req.LineAmountTypes);

        If(req.Salesforce_Account_Id != NULL && String.isNotBlank(req.Salesforce_Account_Id))
            xeroInvoiceMap.put('Salesforce_Account_Id', req.Salesforce_Account_Id);

        If(req.Salesforce_Opportunity_Id != NULL && String.isNotBlank(req.Salesforce_Opportunity_Id))
            xeroInvoiceMap.put('Salesforce_Opportunity_Id', req.Salesforce_Opportunity_Id);

        xeroInvoiceMap.put('Contact', xeroInvoiceContactRefMap);

        // Assign values of Request to Xero Invoice Lines
        List<Object> lineItemList = new List<Object>();
        if(req.invoiceLines != null){
            for(SObject sobj : req.invoiceLines){
                Map<String, Object> xeroInvoiceLineMap = new Map<String, Object>(); 
                List<Object> xeroInvoiceLineTrackingMapList = new List<Object>(); 
                Map<String, Object> xeroInvoiceLineTrackingMap1 = new Map<String, Object>(); 
                Map<String, Object> xeroInvoiceLineTrackingMap2 = new Map<String, Object>(); 
                If(req.ItemCode != NULL && String.isNotBlank(req.ItemCode))
                    xeroInvoiceLineMap.put('ItemCode', sobj.get(req.ItemCode));

                If(req.Description != NULL && String.isNotBlank(req.Description))
                    xeroInvoiceLineMap.put('Description', sobj.get(req.Description));

                If(req.TaxType != NULL && String.isNotBlank(req.TaxType))
                    xeroInvoiceLineMap.put('TaxType', sobj.get(req.TaxType));

                If(req.AccountCode != NULL && String.isNotBlank(req.AccountCode))
                    xeroInvoiceLineMap.put('AccountCode', sobj.get(req.AccountCode));

                If(req.LineItemID != NULL && String.isNotBlank(req.LineItemID))
                    xeroInvoiceLineMap.put('LineItemID', sobj.get(req.LineItemID));

                If(req.UnitAmount != NULL)
                    xeroInvoiceLineMap.put('UnitAmount', sobj.get(req.UnitAmount));

                If(req.TaxAmount != NULL)
                    xeroInvoiceLineMap.put('TaxAmount', sobj.get(req.TaxAmount));

                If(req.LineAmount != NULL)
                    xeroInvoiceLineMap.put('LineAmount', sobj.get(req.LineAmount));

                If(req.Quantity != NULL)
                    xeroInvoiceLineMap.put('Quantity', sobj.get(req.Quantity));

                If(req.DiscountRate != NULL)
                    xeroInvoiceLineMap.put('DiscountRate', sobj.get(req.DiscountRate));

                If(req.TrackingCategoryID1 != NULL)
                    xeroInvoiceLineTrackingMap1.put('TrackingCategoryID', sobj.get(req.TrackingCategoryID1));

                If(req.TrackingCategoryName1 != NULL)
                    xeroInvoiceLineTrackingMap1.put('Name', sobj.get(req.TrackingCategoryName1));

                If(req.TrackingCategoryOption1 != NULL)
                    xeroInvoiceLineTrackingMap1.put('Option', sobj.get(req.TrackingCategoryOption1));

                If(req.TrackingCategoryID2 != NULL)
                    xeroInvoiceLineTrackingMap2.put('TrackingCategoryID', sobj.get(req.TrackingCategoryID2));

                If(req.TrackingCategoryName2 != NULL)
                    xeroInvoiceLineTrackingMap2.put('Name', sobj.get(req.TrackingCategoryName2));

                If(req.TrackingCategoryOption2 != NULL)
                    xeroInvoiceLineTrackingMap2.put('Option', sobj.get(req.TrackingCategoryOption2));

                xeroInvoiceLineTrackingMapList.add(xeroInvoiceLineTrackingMap1);
                xeroInvoiceLineTrackingMapList.add(xeroInvoiceLineTrackingMap2);
                xeroInvoiceLineMap.put('Tracking', xeroInvoiceLineTrackingMapList);
                lineItemList.add(xeroInvoiceLineMap);
            }
        }
        xeroInvoiceMap.put('LineItems',lineItemList);

        return xeroInvoiceMap;
    }
```

Comment: The problem is in part:
  **singleInvoice.Order_Lookup__c  = '';** 
How to put there an Order Id from Flow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to update the `generateXeroInvoiceMap` method to add this to the map that is generated so that you can reference it.

This will mean updating that method to include:

```
If(req.OrderId!= NULL && String.isNotBlank(req.OrderId))
            xeroInvoiceContactRefMap.put('OrderId', req.OrderId);
```

You will then be able to reference this value from the map within the createXeroInvoice method like the other data attributes by using:

```
singleInvoice.Order_Lookup__c = xeroInvoiceList[0].get('OrderId');
```

NOTE: An important assumption I have made in this answer is that the Order Id is the same across the invoices. If that isn't the case, then you'll need to match the returned Salesforce Record Id to the Order Ids that are being sent initially.

Comment: Hi Callum!

Thank you very much for your answer. I added first part to generateXeroInvoiceMap, but it caused errors: 
- Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void get(String) from the type Object
- Variable does not exist: OrderId

Comment: '//Make a request to Xero
       Map<String, Object> respMap = Bread_Winner.BreadwinnerXeroAPI.call(finalReqMap);
        String respJSONString = String.valueof(respMap.get('responseJSON'));
        InvoiceListWrapper invWrapper =(InvoiceListWrapper)JSON.deserialize(respJSONString,InvoiceListWrapper.class);
        String invoiceId = invWrapper.invoices[0].SalesforceRecordId;
        Bread_Winner__Invoice__c singleInvoice = [SELECT Id, Order_Lookup__c  FROM Bread_Winner__Invoice__c where Id = :invoiceId limit 1];
        singleInvoice.Order_Lookup__c = xeroInvoiceList[0].get('OrderId');'

Comment: It is first updated part

Comment: Updated second part:

Comment: public static Map<String, Object> generateXeroInvoiceMap(Requests req){
        Map<String, Object> xeroInvoiceMap = new Map<String, Object>(); 
        // Assign values from the Request to Xero Invoice
        Map<String,Object> xeroInvoiceContactRefMap = new Map<String,Object>();
        xeroInvoiceMap.put('Type','ACCREC');

        If(req.OrderId!= NULL && String.isNotBlank(req.OrderId))
            xeroInvoiceContactRefMap.put('OrderId', req.OrderId);

Comment: We create Invoices upon 1 Order, so Order Id is the same across invoices.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much Callum, your response helped me a lot. I resolved the issue. Please, find my updated code below:

```
// Start Apex Class
public with sharing class CreateXeroInvoiceRunAsync {
    public CreateXeroInvoiceRunAsync() {

    }
    @InvocableMethod(label='Create Xero Invoice' description='Create Xero Invoice')
    public static void createXeroInvoice(List<Requests> requestList){
        List<Response> resToBeReturnedList = new List<Response>();
        List<Object> xeroInvoiceList = new List<Object>();
        String xeroOrgIdValue = '';
        List<Object> OrderList = new List<Order>();
        String OrderIdValue = '';

        for(Requests req : requestList){
            If(req.xeroOrgId != NULL && String.isNotBlank(req.xeroOrgId))
                xeroOrgIdValue = req.xeroOrgId;
            If(req.OrderId!= NULL && String.isNotBlank(req.OrderId))
                OrderIdValue = req.OrderId;

            xeroInvoiceList.add(generateXeroInvoiceMap(req));
        }

        // Sending request to Xero via exposed Global API
        Map<String, Object> reqJSONMap = new Map<String, Object>(); 
        reqJSONMap.put('invoices' , xeroInvoiceList);
        String reqJSON = JSON.serialize(reqJSONMap); 

        Map<String, Object> finalReqMap = new Map<String, Object>(); 
        finalReqMap.put('version' , '1.0'); 
        finalReqMap.put('action' , 'createInvoice');
        finalReqMap.put('RequestJSON' , reqJSON); 
        If(xeroOrgIdValue != NULL && String.isNotBlank(xeroOrgIdValue))
            finalReqMap.put('xeroOrgId' , xeroOrgIdValue);
        System.debug('Request ::: ' + finalReqMap); 
  
        // Make a request to Xero
        Map<String, Object> respMap = Bread_Winner.BreadwinnerXeroAPI.call(finalReqMap);
        String respJSONString = String.valueof(respMap.get('responseJSON'));
        InvoiceListWrapper invWrapper = (InvoiceListWrapper)JSON.deserialize(respJSONString,InvoiceListWrapper.class);
        String invoiceId = invWrapper.invoices[0].SalesforceRecordId;
        Bread_Winner__Invoice__c singleInvoice = [SELECT Id, Order_Lookup__c  FROM Bread_Winner__Invoice__c where Id = :invoiceId limit 1];
        singleInvoice.Order_Lookup__c = OrderIdValue;
            update singleInvoice;
        }
    public class InvoiceWrapper{
        public String SalesforceRecordId;
    }
    public class InvoiceListWrapper{
        public List<InvoiceWrapper> invoices;
    }


    public class Response{
        @InvocableVariable(label='status Code' description='Status of the request')
        public String statusCode;

        @InvocableVariable(label='Error' description='Error')
        public String error;
    }

    public class Requests{
        @InvocableVariable(label='Xero Org Id' description='Xero Org Id')
        public String xeroOrgId;
        
        @InvocableVariable(label='OrderId' description='OrderId')
        public String OrderId;

        @InvocableVariable(label='Xero Contact ID' description='Xero Contact ID')
        public String ContactID;

        @InvocableVariable(label='Date' description='Date')
        public Date DateString;

        @InvocableVariable(label='Due Date' description='Due Date')
        public Date DueDateString;

        @InvocableVariable(label='Status' description='Status')
        public String Status;

        @InvocableVariable(label='InvoiceNumber' description='InvoiceNumber')
        public String InvoiceNumber;

        @InvocableVariable(label='Reference' description='Reference')
        public String Reference;

        @InvocableVariable(label='Line Amount Types' description='Line Amount Types')
        public String LineAmountTypes;

        @InvocableVariable(label='Salesforce Account Id' description='Salesforce Account Id')
        public String Salesforce_Account_Id;

        @InvocableVariable(label='Salesforce Opportunity Id' description='Salesforce Opportunity Id')
        public String Salesforce_Opportunity_Id;

        @InvocableVariable(label='Line Item Code' description='Line Item Code')
        public STRING ItemCode;

        @InvocableVariable(label='Line Description' description='Line Description')
        public STRING Description;

        @InvocableVariable(label='Line Tax Type' description='Line Tax Type')
        public STRING TaxType;

        @InvocableVariable(label='Line Account Code' description='Line Account Code')
        public STRING AccountCode;

        @InvocableVariable(label='Line Line Item ID' description='Line Line Item ID')
        public STRING LineItemID;

        @InvocableVariable(label='Line Unit Amount' description='Line Unit Amount')
        public STRING UnitAmount;

        @InvocableVariable(label='Line Tax Amount' description='Line Tax Amount')
        public STRING TaxAmount;

        @InvocableVariable(label='Line Line Amount' description='Line Line Amount')
        public STRING LineAmount;

        @InvocableVariable(label='Line Quantity' description='Line Quantity')
        public STRING Quantity;

        @InvocableVariable(label='Line Discount Rate' description='Line Discount Rate')
        public STRING DiscountRate;

        @InvocableVariable(label='Line Tracking Category ID 1' description='Line Tracking Category ID 1')
        public STRING TrackingCategoryID1;

        @InvocableVariable(label='Line Tracking Category Name 1' description='Line Tracking Category Name 1')
        public STRING TrackingCategoryName1;

        @InvocableVariable(label='Line Tracking Category Option 1' description='Line Tracking Category Option 1')
        public STRING TrackingCategoryOption1;

        @InvocableVariable(label='Line Tracking Category ID 2' description='Line Tracking Category ID 2')
        public STRING TrackingCategoryID2;

        @InvocableVariable(label='Line Tracking Category Name 2' description='Line Tracking Category Name 2')
        public STRING TrackingCategoryName2;

        @InvocableVariable(label='Line Tracking Category Option 2' description='Line Tracking Category Option 2')
        public STRING TrackingCategoryOption2;

        @InvocableVariable(label='Invoice Line Items' description='Invoice Line Items') 
        public List<SObject> invoiceLines; 


    }

    public static Map<String, Object> generateXeroInvoiceMap(Requests req){
        Map<String, Object> xeroInvoiceMap = new Map<String, Object>(); 
        // Assign values from the Request to Xero Invoice
        Map<String,Object> xeroInvoiceContactRefMap = new Map<String,Object>();
        xeroInvoiceMap.put('Type','ACCREC');
        
        If(req.OrderId != NULL && String.isNotBlank(req.OrderId))
            xeroInvoiceMap.put('OrderId', req.OrderId);        

        If(req.ContactID != NULL && String.isNotBlank(req.ContactID))
            xeroInvoiceContactRefMap.put('ContactID', req.ContactID);

        If(req.DateString != NULL)
            xeroInvoiceMap.put('DateString', DateTime.newInstance(req.DateString.year(), req.DateString.month(), req.DateString.day()).format('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss'));

        If(req.DueDateString != NULL)
            xeroInvoiceMap.put('DueDateString', DateTime.newInstance(req.DueDateString.year(), req.DueDateString.month(), req.DueDateString.day()).format('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss'));

        If(req.Status != NULL && String.isNotBlank(req.Status))
            xeroInvoiceMap.put('Status', req.Status);

        If(req.Reference != NULL && String.isNotBlank(req.Reference))
            xeroInvoiceMap.put('Reference', req.Reference);

        If(req.InvoiceNumber != NULL && String.isNotBlank(req.InvoiceNumber))
            xeroInvoiceMap.put('InvoiceNumber', req.InvoiceNumber);

        If(req.LineAmountTypes != NULL && String.isNotBlank(req.LineAmountTypes))
            xeroInvoiceMap.put('LineAmountTypes', req.LineAmountTypes);

        If(req.Salesforce_Account_Id != NULL && String.isNotBlank(req.Salesforce_Account_Id))
            xeroInvoiceMap.put('Salesforce_Account_Id', req.Salesforce_Account_Id);

        If(req.Salesforce_Opportunity_Id != NULL && String.isNotBlank(req.Salesforce_Opportunity_Id))
            xeroInvoiceMap.put('Salesforce_Opportunity_Id', req.Salesforce_Opportunity_Id);

        xeroInvoiceMap.put('Contact', xeroInvoiceContactRefMap);

        // Assign values of Request to Xero Invoice Lines
        List<Object> lineItemList = new List<Object>();
        if(req.invoiceLines != null){
            for(SObject sobj : req.invoiceLines){
                Map<String, Object> xeroInvoiceLineMap = new Map<String, Object>(); 
                List<Object> xeroInvoiceLineTrackingMapList = new List<Object>(); 
                Map<String, Object> xeroInvoiceLineTrackingMap1 = new Map<String, Object>(); 
                Map<String, Object> xeroInvoiceLineTrackingMap2 = new Map<String, Object>(); 
                If(req.ItemCode != NULL && String.isNotBlank(req.ItemCode))
                    xeroInvoiceLineMap.put('ItemCode', sobj.get(req.ItemCode));

                If(req.Description != NULL && String.isNotBlank(req.Description))
                    xeroInvoiceLineMap.put('Description', sobj.get(req.Description));

                If(req.TaxType != NULL && String.isNotBlank(req.TaxType))
                    xeroInvoiceLineMap.put('TaxType', sobj.get(req.TaxType));

                If(req.AccountCode != NULL && String.isNotBlank(req.AccountCode))
                    xeroInvoiceLineMap.put('AccountCode', sobj.get(req.AccountCode));

                If(req.LineItemID != NULL && String.isNotBlank(req.LineItemID))
                    xeroInvoiceLineMap.put('LineItemID', sobj.get(req.LineItemID));

                If(req.UnitAmount != NULL)
                    xeroInvoiceLineMap.put('UnitAmount', sobj.get(req.UnitAmount));

                If(req.TaxAmount != NULL)
                    xeroInvoiceLineMap.put('TaxAmount', sobj.get(req.TaxAmount));

                If(req.LineAmount != NULL)
                    xeroInvoiceLineMap.put('LineAmount', sobj.get(req.LineAmount));

                If(req.Quantity != NULL)
                    xeroInvoiceLineMap.put('Quantity', sobj.get(req.Quantity));

                If(req.DiscountRate != NULL)
                    xeroInvoiceLineMap.put('DiscountRate', sobj.get(req.DiscountRate));

                If(req.TrackingCategoryID1 != NULL)
                    xeroInvoiceLineTrackingMap1.put('TrackingCategoryID', sobj.get(req.TrackingCategoryID1));

                If(req.TrackingCategoryName1 != NULL)
                    xeroInvoiceLineTrackingMap1.put('Name', sobj.get(req.TrackingCategoryName1));

                If(req.TrackingCategoryOption1 != NULL)
                    xeroInvoiceLineTrackingMap1.put('Option', sobj.get(req.TrackingCategoryOption1));

                If(req.TrackingCategoryID2 != NULL)
                    xeroInvoiceLineTrackingMap2.put('TrackingCategoryID', sobj.get(req.TrackingCategoryID2));

                If(req.TrackingCategoryName2 != NULL)
                    xeroInvoiceLineTrackingMap2.put('Name', sobj.get(req.TrackingCategoryName2));

                If(req.TrackingCategoryOption2 != NULL)
                    xeroInvoiceLineTrackingMap2.put('Option', sobj.get(req.TrackingCategoryOption2));

                xeroInvoiceLineTrackingMapList.add(xeroInvoiceLineTrackingMap1);
                xeroInvoiceLineTrackingMapList.add(xeroInvoiceLineTrackingMap2);
                xeroInvoiceLineMap.put('Tracking', xeroInvoiceLineTrackingMapList);
                lineItemList.add(xeroInvoiceLineMap);
            }
        }
        xeroInvoiceMap.put('LineItems',lineItemList);

        return xeroInvoiceMap;
    }
}
```